# React-stripe-checkout onToken pass parameter or access state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using the react-stripe-checkout form to collect the customer and card information and get the token. This is working great so far.
After the popup dialog is finished the onToken function is called to send the token to the Backend, the problem is I would need another information from the state to send to the Backend and I don't know how to access that

I cannot access this.state

```js
  async onToken(token){
    console.log(this.state) //Error, state undefined
    console.log('Stripe Token: ', token)
    var result = await API.post("videos", "videos/offer/"+this.state.videoid, {
      body: {'price': this.state.pricePerMin, 'token': token}
    });
  }
```

Render Function:

```js
StripeCheckout
        stripeKey=""
        name=""
        token={this.onToken}
        label={'Pay ' + this.state.price + '€ and start video analysis'}
        description={this.state.price+'€ (' + this.state.minutesToPay + ' x ' + this.state.pricePerMin + '€)'}
      amount={10 * 100} // cents
      currency="EUR"
      locale="de"
      shippingAddress={false}
      billingAddress={true}
      // Note: enabling both zipCode checks and billing or shipping address will
      // cause zipCheck to be pulled from billing address (set to shipping if none provided).
      zipCode={true}
      alipay={false} // accept Alipay (default false)
      bitcoin={false}  // accept Bitcoins (default false)
      allowRememberMe // "Remember Me" option (default true)
      />
```

To make the api call I would need the videoid from the state in the onToken function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue

One:
change

```
async onToken(token){
```

to

```
const onToken = async (token) => {
```

The other is

```
token={this.onToken.bind(this)}
```